# framer motion scroll animation only when scroll down not while scroll up

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, css-animations, framer-motion

I have gone through the framer motion scroll trigger documentation. I want to know if there is a way to animate the div every time only while scrolling down not scrolling up.

Suppose there is 3 section 1, 2 and 3. I scroll down to section 2 div will animate. But If scroll up from section 3 to 2 div will again animate. I want only to animate from scrolling down from 1 to 2 not while scrolling up.

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/framer-motion-5-3-scroll-triggered-animations-forked-8ppph7

You will see card animate while scrolling up as well as down. is there a way to solve this so that it animates only while scrolling down and while scrolling up, the div should stay as it is.

My code is section is here

```
const cardVariants: Variants = {
  offscreen: {
    y: 300,
  },
  onscreen: {
    y: 50,
    rotate: -10,
    transition: {
      type: "spring",
      bounce: 0.4,
      duration: 0.8,
    },
  },
};


function Card({ emoji, hueA, hueB }: Props) {
  const background = `linear-gradient(306deg, ${hue(hueA)}, ${hue(hueB)})`;

  return (
    <motion.div
      className="card-container"
      initial="offscreen"
      whileInView="onscreen"
      viewport={{ once: false, amount: 0.8 }}
    >
      <div className="splash" style={{ background }} />
      <motion.div className="card" variants={cardVariants}>
        {emoji}
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```